# Using javascript to post form in iframe, but the iframe source does not change with larger files

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe, submit

I've got a bunch of javascript working on this page so that users can fill the form which includes a file upload field. They can add these forms to a "queue" which is just a series of iframes with the forms data moved into it. With the click of a button it will go through each form and submit them one at a time. When each form is submitted I load a gif to show that there is action. When the processing page is finished it will spit some jquery back at the iframe and give a success or error message. This works great so long as the files are not too large. It seems that the larger files (near 1GB) results in a condition where the jquery from the processing page never shows up in the iframe. This is disastrous because the submitting page will not continue to submit forms unless it gets some sort of response. Also the user is left with a spinning image that never goes away, and are unsure if even one large file has actually uploaded. I've tried setting the max_execution_time and max_input_time for an hour, but this doesn't help at all. Currently using a jquery/javascript to loop through each form and submit it. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and/or how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout with jQuery ajax to be longer - From the documentation.

timeoutNumber
Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the request times out; accessing any object members may throw an exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

Comment: Thank you nobody! After some playing around with that everything seems to be working with large files.